# Center of mass in pyramids.

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I have several questions to verify and my fill the gaps in my knowledge on centers of mass in pyramids. I would be also very grateful if you could verify the informations I already have.

So, I know that the center of mass of tetrahedron is called a centroid. According to Wikipedia: "A line segment joining a vertex of a tetrahedron with the centroid of the opposite face is called a median and a line segment joining the midpoints of two opposite edges is called a bimedian of the tetrahedron. Hence there are four medians and three bimedians in a tetrahedron. These seven line segments are all concurrent at a point called the centroid of the tetrahedron. In addition the four medians are divided in a 3:1 ratio".

Now, I would like to expand that properties on other pyramids. Those are my questions.

1)
Does the center of the mass of tetrahedron lay in the orthocenter?

1.1)
Is there any pyramid other than the tetrahedron that has center of the mass and orthocenter in the same place (all regular pyramids? all regular triangular pyramids?)?

1.2)
Is there any pyramid other than the tetrahedron that has a orthocenter (all regular pyramids? all regular triangular pyramids?)?

2)
If I draw a line between the vortex and the center of mass of the base in ANY triangular pyramid will it be located in the crossing of all 4 medians and 3 bimedians? Will the piont of crossing devide medians in 3:1 ratio? I mean to apply this rule to the triangular pyramids in which the projection of the vertex on the base is not in the center of mass of the base. What about all regular triangular pyramids?

2.1)
Does it work for every pyramid with odd number of edges in the base?

2.2)
What about the ratio of bimedians? Is there any fixed ration of their division?

3)
In the case of pyramids with an even number of edges in the base, according to the theory, there is just one median (joining a vertex of a tetrahedron with the centroid of the base). Therefore, it can not be crossed by any other. There are however 2 tipes of possible "bimedians" corssing the height of pyramid, each one of them: (1) joining the midpoint of the base edge with the midpoint of height in side face ; (2) joining the midpoint of the side edge with the vertex in the base.

Does one tipe of those bimedians devide the existing median in any fixed ratio? Does it work in ANY pyramid with an even number of edges in the base (regular ones? those with projection of the vertex on the base out of the center of mass of the base?)?

I would appreciate it if you could help me. I know that there are a lot of questions. You don't need to answer them all at once. Every answer would be helpful.

Comment: I'd suggest you to experiment a bit with GeoGebra: you'll find the answer to most of your questions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah, I have already tried using GeoGebra and I couldn't answer any of my questions. Either my skills are not sufficient or it is impossible to see the angles and ratios on these 3d diagrams. I also thought that for some people with great knowledge of gemetry it might be easy to answer all of them since those things are probably formulated as general rules of mathematics and they don't change.

Comment: Sorry but I can't believe you really tried: constructing a triangular base pyramid with GeoGebra is an easy way to answer your questions 2, 2.1, 2.2. Moreover, you seem to use the word "tetrahedron" as a synonymous  of "regular tetrahedron", but that's not of general use: a "tetrahedron" is any triangular base pyramid.

Comment: Thank you for the remark considering the use of term "tetrahedron" - of course you are right, I'm sorry :) I really spent some time using GeoGebra and I really couldn't find anything out. However, by serching Stack Exchange I was able to find a great proof of medians of a tetrahedron being concurrent that contains informations about the ratio at which they intersect each other - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680158/center-of-mass-of-a-tetrahedron?rq=1. I conclude that because of mass, in every tetrahedron medians are divided in a 3:1 ratio and bimedians are divided in a 1:1 ratio.

Comment: By simple expansion of that theory, in every square pyramid the median connecting base with the apex is divided by the center of mass in the ratio 1:4. Every "bimedian" of 1st type (I don't know if they are called that way if they are not in tetrahedron) joining a midpoint of the base edge with a center of mass of a face is divided by the center of mass in the ratio 2:3. Accordingly same theory can be applied to other pyramids - it's easy to find the ratio dividing median connecting base with the apex and hard to find other ones since in no other way the points lay in one plane. Am I right?

Comment: The median connecting base with vertex is divided by the center of mass in the ratio 1:3 in EVERY pyramid. You should not confuse the center of mass of isolated points with the center of mass of a solid figure.

Comment: Thank you very much. On Wikipedia it is said that: "The geometric centroid coincides with the center of mass if the mass is uniformly distributed over the whole simplex, or concentrated at the vertices as n equal masses" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid). Therefore that way of thinking is only applicable to simplexes. Since bimedians also do intersect in the center of mass in tetrahedron - do you know if there is any fixed ratio of their division?

Comment: Bimedians in a tetrahedron intersect at their midpoint.